# how to resolve image directory in android

Tags: android, file-upload

I'm picking an image from my android emulator gallery in order to serve it to the server but whenever I tried that, I got this error D/Main: /document/1AE6-2C19:Download/food2.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory). I have tried all the solutions for similar problems from stack overflow here yet that couldn't be resolved.
Here is the code

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode== PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode== RESULT_OK ){

            profileImageUri = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),profileImageUri);
                profilePicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            profileImagePath = profileImageUri.toString();
        }
    }
    
    
    public void uploadProfileImage(){
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),profileImagePath);
        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file",profileImagePath,requestBody);

        Call<ImageDto> imageDtoCall = BaseUrlClient
                .getInstance().getApi().uploadProfileImage(body);
        imageDtoCall.enqueue(new Callback<ImageDto>() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ImageDto> call, Response<ImageDto> response) {
                if (response.code()==201){
                    assert response.body() != null;
                    Log.d("Main","The image url is "+response.body().getDownloadUrl());
                    //createPatient(response.body().getDownloadUrl());
                }else {
                    Log.d("Main","Response code is "+response.code());
                    Toast.makeText(PatientRegistrationActivity.this, "Error Uploading Profile Image, Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        Log.d("Main",response.errorBody().string());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ImageDto> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Main",t.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(PatientRegistrationActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }

My Interface

@Multipart
    @POST("profileImage/upload")
    Call<ImageDto> uploadProfileImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part image);

My baseUrl class 

public class BaseUrlClient {

    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.43.5:8080/";

    private static BaseUrlClient mInstance;
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    private BaseUrlClient(){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                //.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    public static synchronized BaseUrlClient getInstance(){
        if (mInstance ==null){
            mInstance = new BaseUrlClient();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
    public ApiClient getApi(){
        return retrofit.create(ApiClient.class);
    }
}


Response class

public class ImageDto {

    private String fileName;
    private String downloadUrl;
    private String fileType;
    private long fileSize;

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public String getDownloadUrl() {
        return downloadUrl;
    }

    public String getFileType() {
        return fileType;
    }

    public long getFileSize() {
        return fileSize;
    }

    public ImageDto() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Uri.getPath() gives you an impossible path as you have seen. Not a file system path. Use the whole uri (uri.toString()) to upload your file. Dont use the File class.

Comment: Thanks @blackapps, I have solved that issue but there is another issue

Comment: From the backend, you can use the image url and get the image from the browser but when I copied the url to the browser to download the image, the image is downloaded but when I click to open it, I had this error that says C:\Users\HP\Downloads\content_com.android.externalstorage.documents_document_1AE6-2C19_Download_food(1).jpg Paint cannot read this file. This is not a valid bitmap file, or its format is not currently supported

Comment: Even if I paste the image Url in post man and make a GET request with it, it returns 200 response code but the image cannot be displayed. Please I need guides on how to resolve this because I want the user to be able to retrieve his/her profile image when login

Comment: We dont know how you uploaded the image. Further you should tell filesize of original and copy. And filesize on server.

Comment: please can you add more explanation on the filesize stuff, I don't really understand what to do?

Comment: Please I have updated my question with the code I used to saved the image into the server after you gave me the first correction, please check back the code in my question and suggest on what I should do. thanks

Comment: I will not look. You should first tell three file sizes as asked for.

Comment: Sorry for that, the file size is 89Bytes, I stored the image in MySQL database in a blob format.

Comment: An image file of 89 bytes? How will that go? Then tell how many bytes the server received. And tell the size of the blob. And then tell the size of the downloaded file. I asked for three sizes didnt i?

Comment: the actual size of the image is 9KB, the size in the database i.e as stored in the blob format is 89B and the downloaded size is 1KB. If I save the same image to the server through postman, the stuff is working correctly(i.e I can be able to download it without any issue), I only have the issue while sending it through android app in which I thought that the issue is from wrong formatting

Comment: I expect you to comment on these eighty nine bytes before you complain about a wrong download. And why is the downloaded file one kilo byte instead of eighty nine bytes? We conclude: upload goes wrong. Download goes wrong too. With upload less bytes. With download more. And you did tell nothing of this all.

Comment: yes, that's why I needed the help. The issue is definitely from my upload. That was why I pasted the code for uploading the image so that you can go through it and probable figure out what goes wrong in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250271/discussion-between-ukeme-elijah-and-blackapps).